# google-services.json contains 2 x client_info

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The new GCM implementation from google is super easy and everything but a client has thrown away their keystore and has requested to change the package name so I followed the guide from google for a new [configuration file](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). This is awesome and everything but since I've allready added one I now get a generated file with 2 client configurations in it (see below).

I was just wondering if I can remove 1 without problems, or if we can do something from console. In console there is nothing else but 1 credential for the server so there is nothing indicating the credentials... Alternatively I have to create a new project (no biggy actually but still maybe someone had an idea).

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "xxx",
    "project_number": "123123",
    "name": "Project"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "key",
        "client_id": "android:package.name",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "package.name"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "key",
        "client_id": "android:package.name_2",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "package.name_2"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
}
```

Comment: I think the initial package name is still associated with your project in some way and thus is still being added to the config file. You should be able to remove the unwanted client from the config file with no issues.

Comment: @ArthurThompson I think so to, but for now I just have both in the file and it works... so not optimal but I wasn't in a position where I could play around with it or take chances =/ why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went with having both in the file and it haven't caused any issues. I'm pretty sure I could just delete one of them like Arthur Thompson suggested but this is the way I've decided to use it for now.

Comment: do we need oauth-client details under client information in the google-services.json? Can't we delete all of them?

Comment: @SethuramanSrinivasan I don't know. I don't think I'd tinker too much with it as I frankly don't care. I just want it to work.